# Paper which proves that any polynomial dominates any poly-logarithmic function?

Tags: polynomials, reference-request, logarithms, asymptotics

Does anybody know a paper which proves that $x^k$ dominates $log^c(x)$, where $k$ and $c$ are constants.

In particular I only need that $x$ dominates $log^c(x)$.

The user @fmnijk proved it in his answer for [Polylogarithm grows slower than polynomial proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3096083/polylogarithm-grows-slower-than-polynomial-proof), but I guess this is not a source I should quote in a paper.

Comment: You can copy the essence of my argument, more or less, to show that, if $P,Q$ are polynomials with $P$ non-constant, then: $$\lim_{x\to0}P(x)Q(\log x)=0$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is just a well known fact and, in my opinion, you may state it or use it without comment, as any paper I’ve ever read would do/has done. Seriously, papers tend to skip many steps, or say: “obviously, [...]”, without further justification, so in particular a result of analysis as basic as this would be neglected from comment by most authors.

If you want a proof that is in the style of a paper, I may suggest the following. It is as briefly written as I would expect to see, take it or leave it (I acknowledge it is highly similar to the proof you link).

let $P$,$Q$ be real or complex polynomials and let $x$ range over the positive reals. To show: $$\frac{P(\log x)}{Q(x)}\to0$$As $x\to\infty$, it is equivalent to show: $$\frac{P(x)}{Q(e^x)}\to0$$As $x\to\infty$. In the application of L’Hopital’s rule (valid, since the numerator and denominator diverge) the “degree” of $Q$ is never reduced whereas the degree of $P(x)$, say $m$, will reduce; $m$ applications of L’Hopital’s rule reduces the numerator to a constant, and the denominator will remain a polynomial expression in $e^x$. You are left with a limit of $0$.

Comment: Wow, I did not expect the proof to be that simple. I think I will just state it without explaining it too deep then, as it seems not uncommon to do. Thank you very much!

Comment: @tonik You’re very welcome